# Ruby CSV::Table sort in place

Tags: ruby, sorting, csv

I'm sorting a `CSV::Table` object. I have a table with headers (`"date"`, `"amount"`, `"source"`) and `O(50)` entries.

Input:

```
data = CSV.table('filename.csv', headers:true) # note headers are :date, :source, :amount

amounts = []
data[:amount].each {|i| amounts << i.to_f}

data.sort_by! {|row| row[:amount]} 
# error - not a defined function

data = data.sort_by {|row| row[:amount]} 
# sorted but data is now an array not CSV::Table. would like to retain access to headers
```

I want a bang function to sort the table in place by the `"amount"` column without loosing the `CSV::Table` structure.  Specifically, I want the result to be a CSV::Table, so that I still have access to the headers.  Right now, I'm getting an Array, which is not what I want.

I'm sure there is an easier way to do this, especially with the `CSV::Table` class. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by loosing the structure?

Comment: Good question! Was hoping that CSV::Table class had a sort_by method that returned a CSV:Table with the same headers. It seems that this is not the case - correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`CSV::Table.new(data)` to convert Array to CSV::Table object if that is what you want.

`sort_by` is a method from Enumerable module which will always return an array when block is given as an argument

Comment: Thank you for this. How would you sort a CSV::Table? Would the easiset way be something like:
    CSV::Table.new(table.sort_by { |row| row[:amount]})

Comment: Yes that sorting method looks fine. However you need to ask yourself if converting the sorted data to CSV::Table is really what you need. If you really need to have headers you can always get them before sorting :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you define the following string:

```
txt=<<-CSV_TXT
Item, Type, Amount, Date
gasoline, expense, 200.00, 2022-01-01
Food, expense, 25.66, 2021-12-24
Plates, expense, 333.03, 2021-04-24
Presents, expense, 1500.01, 2021-12-15
Pay check, income, 2000, 2021-12-07
Consulting, income, 300, 2021-12-16
CSV_TXT
# for giggles, using a multi character separator of ', '
```

Now create a CSV Table from that (this in the IRB...):

```
> require 'csv'
=> true
> options={:col_sep=>", ", :headers=>true, :return_headers=>true}
=> {:col_sep=>", ", :headers=>true, :return_headers=>true}
> data=CSV.parse(txt, **options)
=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:7>
```

We now have a `CSV::Table` with a header defined. If you use `CSV::Table` the header is not optional.

There are two ways (that I know of) you can now sort this table by the `Date` field and end up with a `CSV::Table` with the header unchanged. Neither is fully an 'in-place' solution.

The first, create a new `CSV::Table` after a round trip an array of `CSV::Rows`. The call to `.sort_by` creates that array of `CSV::Rows` for you and you can index a `CSV::Row` for sorting purposes. You use the first row of the existing table as the header argument:

```
> data=CSV::Table.new([data[0]]+data[1..].sort_by{ |r| r[3] })
=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:7>
```

The second, is similar but allows the header to more easily be split off by using `.to_a` to create an array. This also allows the individual rows to be filtered or otherwise processed further:

```
> data=CSV.parse(txt, **options).to_a
=> 
[["Item", "Type", "Amount", "Date"],
...
> header=data.shift.to_csv(**options)
=> "Item, Type, Amount, Date\n"
```

Now you have `data` with the header split off. With that array, you can sort or filter or process at will; then put back into an array of CSV strings. This is all in place:

```
> data.sort_by!{|r| r[3]}.map!{|r| r.to_csv(**options)}
=> 
["Plates, expense, 333.03, 2021-04-24\n",
 "\"Pay check\", income, 2000, 2021-12-07\n",
 "Presents, expense, 1500.01, 2021-12-15\n",
 "Consulting, income, 300, 2021-12-16\n",
 "Food, expense, 25.66, 2021-12-24\n",
 "gasoline, expense, 200.00, 2022-01-01\n"]
```

(Note the field with `"Pay check"` is quoted. If *any* character from a multi-character `:col_sep` is in a field, Ruby will quote it...)

To print the first, just use `puts data` since Ruby knows how to print a `CSV::Table`; to print the second, you can do `puts header,data.join("")`

For the second, to rejoin the header and data into a new table, use `parse` with `options` again:

```
> data_new=CSV.parse(header+data.join(""), **options)
=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:7>
```