# Rearrange CSV, delete the old one and re-write

Tags: ruby, sorting, csv, hash, export-to-csv

Let's say I have a CSV file

```
Name,Age
john,20
ana,30
steven,25
frank,27
```

What about if I want to order it in descending order depending on "age" value, to have something like this

```
Name,Age
ana,30
frank,27
steven,25
john,20
```

and then delete all the CSV rows and rewrite them depending on the new order?

I know hot to create hashes from the CSV and order it, but not how to achieve the described result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786098/ruby-csvtable-sort-in-place#37786671 might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ruby has a CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html). You can use it to read, sort, and write your CSV files. The `CSV` class is a wrapper around [`CSV::Table`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html#method-i-to_csv). `CSV::Table` deals with the data itself, while `CSV` mostly provides the ability to read from files.

```
require 'csv'
orig_table = CSV.table("test.csv");
```

`orig_table` is a `CSV::Table` object. Unfortunately you can't directly sort its rows in place, but you can sort them into an Array of `CSV::Row` objects and put that into a new `CSV::Table`.

```
sorted_rows = orig_table.sort { |a,b| b[:age] <=> a[:age] }
sorted_table = CSV::Table.new(sorted_rows)
```

Then you can get a CSV string out of that with `to_csv` and write it back to the file.

```
File.open("test.csv", "w").write(sorted_table.to_csv)
```

Comment: @steenslag `to_csv` and `to_s` are the same, so leaving off `to_csv` relies on the default stringification of `sorted_table`.